# Quarkus reasteasy reactive with multipart extension

Tags: resteasy, multipart, quarkus

I'm having an application that relies on quarkus reactive stack, so in order to call external services I have the following dependencies:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I'm now trying to call an endpoint that accepts multipart data, so I've added the following:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-multipart</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

However this seems to be conflicting as the following error occurs while building the app:

```
021-05-24 18:03:35,706 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Failed to start quarkus: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple matching properties for name "security.jaxrs.deny-unannotated-endpoints" property was matched by both public boolean io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs and public boolean io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs. This is likely because you have an incompatible combination of extensions that both define the same properties (e.g. including both reactive and blocking database extensions)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:309)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:182)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:59)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:79)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:378)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:56)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:127)
    at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:84)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:144)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Multiple matching properties for name "security.jaxrs.deny-unannotated-endpoints" property was matched by both public boolean io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs and public boolean io.quarkus.resteasy.reactive.common.runtime.JaxRsSecurityConfig.denyJaxRs. This is likely because you have an incompatible combination of extensions that both define the same properties (e.g. including both reactive and blocking database extensions)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.matching.PatternMapBuilder.addMember(PatternMapBuilder.java:71)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.matching.PatternMapBuilder.addGroup(PatternMapBuilder.java:60)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.matching.PatternMapBuilder.makePatterns(PatternMapBuilder.java:35)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.configuration.BuildTimeConfigurationReader.<init>(BuildTimeConfigurationReader.java:116)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader.loadStepsFrom(ExtensionLoader.java:143)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:101)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:307)
    ... 9 more
```

I can't find the reactive version for multipart dependency. Any clue how to make it working?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can't use

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

with any of the `quarkus-resteasy-reactive` extensions.

`quarkus-resteasy-reactive` already has multipart support built-in, see [this](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#handling-multipart-form-data)

Comment: Sure thing, no problem